# Custom Delete Confirmation popup on Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-scheduler

I would like to create a custom delete confirmation popup on Kendo scheduler control.
How can I accomplish this?
Here is my code below:

```
  $("#sessionScheduler").kendoScheduler({
                height: 600,
                editable: {
                    confirmation: true,
                    create: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    edit: true,
                    update: true,
                    template: $("#session-form-template").html(),
                    window: {
                        title: "Session",
                    }
                },
                eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),
                views: [
                    { type: "day", dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/MM')#</span>" },
                    { type: "week", dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/MM')#</span>" },
                    { type: "workWeek", dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd dd/MM')#</span>" },
                    { type: "month", selected: true },
                    "agenda",
                ],
                // editable: false,
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                 
                remove: function (e) {
                },
            });
```